# Landscape virtual keyboard in android 2.3.3

Tags: android

I am trying to make changes in source code of virtual keyboard in android source code 2.3.3.
As you all know that in android 2.3 there is no LANDSCAPE mode of virtual keyboard.
when we try to pop up keyboard in landscape mode only a white line appears at bottom.

Can anybody tell me about this behavior.
And please also tell me how can I achieve this.
I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I never had this problem on NexusOne (currently at 2.3.4) you may want to specify which phone model you are using and any code you are trying to modify as far as file name, location and line numbers

Answer (score 0):

maybe the keyboard you are trying to edit does not have an XML layout file yet?

quoted from the hello world example [found here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

> **Landscape layout**
>
> When you want a different design for landscape, put your layout XML file inside /res/layout-land. Android will automatically look here when the layout changes. Without this special landscape layout defined, Android will stretch the default layout.